# How to show a table from a slice with my struct

Tags: html, http, go, web

I want to show a table that each row contains my struct data.

Here is my struct:

```
type My_Struct struct {
FIRST_FIELD       string
SECOND_FIELD      string
THIED_FIELD       string
}
```

Here is my html code:

```
<table id="t01">
<tr>
    <th>FIRST FIELD</th>
    <th>SECOND FIELD</th>
    <th>THIRD FIELD</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>FIRST_OBJ_HERE_SHOULD_BE_THE_FIRST_FIELD</td>
    <td>FIRST_OBJ_HERE_SHOULD_BE_THE_SECOND_FIELD</td>
    <td>FIRST_OBJ_HERE_SHOULD_BE_THE_THIRD_FIELD</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>SECOND_OBJ_HERE_SHOULD_BE_THE_FIRST_FIELD</td>
    <td>SECOND_OBJ_HERE_SHOULD_BE_THE_SECOND_FIELD</td>
    <td>SECOND_OBJ_HERE_SHOULD_BE_THE_THIRD_FIELD</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

As you see, I want to pass a slice with my struct (each one contains 3 files) to this html code, and I want the the whole slice will be set in this table - each row contains one struct data.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what didn't work. This should be reasonably straightforward using the [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want the [Go Template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package.

Here's an example of how you may use it:
Define a handler that passes an instance of a struct with some defined field(s) to a view that uses Go Templates:

```
type MyStruct struct {
        SomeField string
}

func MyStructHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ms := MyStruct{
                SomeField: "Hello Friends",
        }

        t := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("./showmystruct.html"))
t.Execute(w, ms)
}
```

Access the struct fields using the Go Template syntax in your view (showmystruct.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Show My Struct</title>
<h1>{{ .SomeField }}</h1>
```

**Update**

If you are interested particularly in passing a list, and iterating over that, then the `{{ range }}` keyword is useful. Also, there's a pretty common pattern (at least in my world) where you pass a `PageData{}` struct to the view.

Here's an expanded example, adding a list of structs, and a `PageData` struct (so we can access its fields in the template):

```
type MyStruct struct {
    SomeField string
}

type PageData struct {
    Title string
    Data []MyStruct
}

func MyStructHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        data := PageData{
            Title: "My Super Awesome Page of Structs",
            Data: []MyStruct{
                MyStruct{
                    SomeField: "Hello Friends",
                },
                MyStruct{
                    SomeField: "Goodbye Friends",
                },
            }

        t := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("./showmystruct.html"))
        t.Execute(w, data)

}
```

And the modified template (showmystruct.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>{{ .Title }}</title>
<ul>
  {{ range .Data }}
    <li>{{ .SomeField }}</li>
  {{ end }}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! But my main problem is passing a list of this struct. How can I access to each struct in the list, within the html code, in that way?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include iterating through a range.